# Angular Image To WebP Gray Square

Tags: angular, image-conversion, angular15

I'm trying to just convert images to ***webp*** in this service below. It **seems** to be working and doing some sort of conversion. However, when I call my test function to trigger a download the downloaded image is just a gray square. Am I doing something wrong here or is there an easier way to do this?

**image-conversion.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOC_ORIENTATION, NgxImageCompressService } from 'ngx-image-compress';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageConversionService {

  constructor(private imageCompress: NgxImageCompressService) { }

  convertToWebP(image: File): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    reader.onload = () => {
      const dataUrl = reader.result as string;
      this.imageCompress.compressFile(dataUrl, DOC_ORIENTATION.Up, 50, 50).then(result => {
        const convertedImage = new File([result], `${image.name.split('.')[0]}.webp`, { type: 'image/webp' });
        console.log('converted and file created!');
        console.log(convertedImage);
        this.downloadFile(convertedImage, "test")
      });
    };
  }


  // test function to trigger download of converted image
  private downloadFile(data: Blob, filename: string): void {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename;
    link.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
}
```

Log results:
[image]

Image:
[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, `ngx-image-compress` outputs JPEG. It doesn't seem to have any option to use WebP, and you haven't given it any. So you're telling the browser that a JPEG file is a WebP. Not too surprising that it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Doh. I was misguided to believe this specifically converted to webp but i see now there's no mention of that. Are there any good libraries for this?

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't know.